# Why did Adaline run away?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-age-of-adaline

I am referring to the scene at the end of the movie where William exposed her and admitted to her that he knows. She is running to Williams house for the car and then she is leaving.

Why did Adaline run and drive away from William and Ellis?
She already was exposed and it isn't clear from what or whom she ran away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adaline ran away from Ellis at the end for the same reason she ran away from William. She knows she doesn't age and that is her secret. First, she doesn't want anyone to know and second, what kind of life would it be to watch your spouse, the person you love dearly, fade away with age while you remain static in time. She has already done that with her daughter.

Keep in mind while William did reveal that he knew it was her, Ellis still did not know. Throughout the movie it was clear that Adaline avoided personal relationships, especially love interests. She was falling in love with Ellis and she knew it. When she realized who William was, she was reminded of what would happen and also realized that she was letting herself get too attached to Ellis, thus breaking her own rules.

Comment: Still, I don't entirely understand. She could have a little speech with William about what to do next, she could say goodbye to Ellis better, she could have done a lot of other things i think...

Comment: @TGar I agree, she could have done things differently at that point in time. Back when she ran away from William it was easy, she just kept on driving and avoided any conflict or having to explain. I don't think Adaline, for all her wisdom and age, learned how to deal with matters of the heart and as such, did not know of any other way.